# How do I configure actix-web to accept CORS requests from any origin?

Tags: rust, cors, actix-web

I am building a REST API with actix-web. How do I configure CORS to accept requests from any origin?

```
Cors::new() // <- Construct CORS middleware builder
    .allowed_origin("localhost:8081")
    .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
    .allowed_headers(vec![http::header::AUTHORIZATION, http::header::ACCEPT])
    .allowed_header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE)
    .max_age(3600)
```

The above code works from the web at `localhost:8081`, but not from `0.0.0.0:8081` or `127.0.0.1:8081`. I tried `"*"` to allow all, but it's not working. How do I allow all, or at least allow a specific origin and then pass multiple URLs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default `All` origins is [allowed](https://docs.rs/actix-cors/0.2.0-alpha.3/actix_cors/struct.Cors.html#method.allowed_origin)

This is my simple CORS setup (allow all origins and methods + allow send credentials)

```rust
Cors::new().supports_credentials()
```

You can start with it, and disallow methods, origins and headers step-by-step.

Comment: This is fine where I want to allow all. What if I want allow specifically 3 urls? say, abc.com, abc.uk, abc.org?

Comment: chain calls of `allowed_origin` on each allowed origin

Comment: I get *error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `Cors` in the current scope*

Comment: @EvanCarroll seems like actix-core was updated - use Cors::default() and checkout actual docs https://docs.rs/actix-cors/0.5.4/actix_cors/struct.Cors.html

Comment: To do the same with the latest version (currently 0.5.4), use `Cors::permissive()`

Answer (score 15):

Starting from `actix-cors = "0.5.0"`, you can use:

```rust
Cors::permissive()
```

However, they recommend against using it in production: https://docs.rs/actix-cors/latest/actix_cors/struct.Cors.html#method.permissive